# I have run error at on Create on Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I get a massage says "app is keep stopping" when I run the project on my mobile.
the error  at on Create(MainActivity.java:16)
at the line 16  set Content View method
help me

Comment: Please post some code & the stacktrace.

Comment: Check this **[unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23353173/7666442)**

Answer (score 0):

The method `setContentView()` sets the `View` that your `MainActivity` should display.

The `View` is usually declared in `layout/activity_main.xml`.

Some error seems to appear when trying to call this method in your application.

---

A common reason why android applications crash there is calling some methods in the overridden method `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` in a wrong order.

Check if your code follows this pattern:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // setContentView call
    
    // other things
}
```

I cannot help you further now, please copy and paste the stacktrace (crash information) into your question. When your application just crashed on an emulator, you can see it in the Run-section (usually red text).